# installing php cURL on IIS

Tags: php, iis, curl

I cannot install PHP-CURL on IIS. I think I have tried everything.

My phpinfo() output does not list cURL as available.
I have C:\PHP in my path and working correctly.
I have edited the registry to read from C:\PHP\php.ini. phpinfo() output shows the correct .ini path loaded.
I have uncommented 'extension=php_curl.dll'
I have ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll availble in C:\PHP

---

- Windows Server 2003
- IIS 6
- PHP 5.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running:

```
php-cgi.exe -v
```

and see if any errors come up.

Also make sure the php is correctly in your path by going to the command line and typing:

```
echo %PATH%
```

As well make sure the php_curl.dll is in the correct directory and that ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll are the same versions.

If all else fails try reinstalling PHP as I remember there being some issues a while back with the Curl Module not working on 5.1.4.

As well someone else mentioned installing the thread safe PHP package versus the non-thread package resolving a similar issue.

Comment: running php-cgi.exe -v fixed my issue.  It gave me an error saying that zlib.dll was missing.    I added that DLL and now it works fine. Thanks a million

Comment: Absolutely perfect. You're a life saver. zlib.dll can be downloaded from http://www.zlib.net/ (rename zlib1.dll to zlib.dll and place in your php folder)

Answer (score 2):

Did you definitely put php_curl.dll in the directory that PHP reads extensions from? Are the file permissions on it ok? And the big question: where did you get the php_curl.dll from? If you got a precompiled one it might be compiled for a different version of PHP than you are running. Check your webserver logs and see what comes up from PHP when you restart the server/container/whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had originally had it from a different version and I had already fixed this.